# Passing Parameters On Ribbon Button Click

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, event-handlers, newform, parameter

I have added a button to the ribbon for a specific content type on a list (parent list).  This is the only content type on the parent list.  When an item in the parent list is selected and then the user clicks the button a child item (using newform.aspx) is to be created that is related to the selected parent item.

How is it possible that I can pass values from the selected parent item (e.g. ID and Category, etc.) to the NewForm.aspx for the child item on click of ribbon button?

Answer (score 1):

Use tokens in your custom action definition to pass values to the new form. More on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458385%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Add another custom action with code behind to handle the new form OnLoad event:

```
<CustomAction Id="NewFormCustomActionId"
                Location="NewFormToolbar"
                ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
                ControlClass="CustomActions.YourCodeBehindNamespace"
                RegistrationType="ContentType"
                RegistrationId="0x010020CA30C66D23475D926915EB818F52B905">
</CustomAction>
```

Handle the OnLoad event and get the values from your query string. If you need to apply default values to the new form, use `SPContext.Current.FormContext.FieldControlCollection`.

I'd suggest you use `{SelectedItemId}` token and with that you will be able to get the parent item from code behind in the newform.aspx:

```
var list = SPContext.Current.List;
var item = list.GetItemById(SelectedItemIdFromQueryString);
```